# How to log a message to ramoops?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, console, init

I want to store a message to ramoops from an init binary.

> init.c

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
   int result = mknod("/dev/console", 0600, 0);
   result = system("/etc/init.d/rcS");
   printf("Hello, World! %i\n", result);
   sleep(999999999);
   return result;
}
```

When I bootup, my kernel isn't throwing any Hello World message. I need to log a message from when I startup. Is there a way to store the message in ramoops eg in `/etc/init.d/rcS`, I mount pstore then try `echo $(ls /) > /sys/fs/pstore/custom-message`

Comment: When a process is started by fork+execve it receives an environment and 3 open file descriptors from it's parent. `init` does not receive anything.  This means you do not have a `stdout` for printf, and you do not have a PATH for `ls`

Comment: so how do I get stdout for printf?

Comment: I guess you can try opening stdout on /dev/console.  It's a little weird for init to have a stderr, stout or stdin open.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending a message to `/dev/kmsg`

```
echo "Hello Kernel-World" > /dev/kmsg
```

I wrote this in the script being executed ( `/etc/init.d/rcS`).
It should only be executed after `/dev/kmsg` is created, eg by `mdev -s`
Reference found here [Printk from userspace](https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing)